# Sort barplot columns ggplot

Tags: r, sorting, bar-chart, ggplot2

I have this R code code to generate the following barplot:

```
d <- data.frame(case = c(1,2,3,4), 
                var=c('foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo','bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'), 
                val=c(9,2,2,4,6,1,2,3))
d$var <- as.factor(d$var)
d$case <- as.factor(d$case)
ggplot(d, aes(x = case, y = val, fill = var)) + scale_x_discrete() + geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

[image]

How can I sort the bars by the value of 'bar'?

Disclaimer: this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746342/sorting-ggplot2-box-plot-by-2-columns but this was not answered, so...

Comment: @Arun I think you just need to modify your answer to sort the levels of `case` by `val` within `foo`, but I agree that this wasn't terribly clear from the question.

Comment: @Arun, thanks for the answer, what I really ment is that I would like to sort the columns not per case but across cases. In my example, if I 'sort the bars by the value of bar', I would like the cases to be displayed in this order: 1, 4, 3, 2

Comment: Arun has basically shown you the way, even though he misread how you wanted it sorted. Just specify the levels of `case` in the desired order.

Comment: Okay after enough trials, now, I think I got it right. Thanks @joran for clarifying the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `order` to get the columns ordered by values for `bar` and replicate it in `foo` as well. Then use this column for `x`.

```
d$case <- match(d$val[d$var == "bar"], sort(d$val[d$var == "bar"]))
d$case <- factor(d$case, levels=1:4)
# now use this:
ggplot(d, aes(x = case, y = val, fill = var)) +  
         geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

(or equivalently)

```
 ggplot(d, aes( x= order, fill = var)) + geom_bar(aes(weights=val), position="dodge")
```

[image]